# Format Words in Left and Right Align Individually

Tags: ms-word, alignment, ms-office

I've the below word format in a word file and am just trying to get the text of the right section justified:

```
Hello                                   Page No
   1.1 Hello 1                             2                                                                                                    
   1.2 Hello 2                         10                                              
   1.3 Hello 3                      14                                                                            
   1.4 Hello 4                         20
```

Is there any shortcut in Microsoft word or power-point 2007 to get the page numbers in the same alignment (Justified) with short key?

I am expecting the below:

```
Hello                                   Page No
   1.1 Hello 1                             2                                                                                                    
   1.2 Hello 2                            10                                              
   1.3 Hello 3                            14                                                                            
   1.4 Hello 4                            20
```

**Update 1** - I've tried splitting pages into two columns but now getting this:

```
Hello                                   
 Page No
     1.1       Hello         1                             
     2                                                                                                    
     1.2       Hello         2                         
     10
```

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/how-to-set-a-tab-in-the-word-2007-tabs-dialog-box/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS-Word go to Page Layout and split your page into two column and align your right column Justified.

Following steps : 
 **Page Layout (Menu)** - **Columns (Sub Menu)** - **Two Columns**.

[image: Sample Image For Formatting]

Try this.

Comment: I've tried your solution and thanks @Kevin Andrid. Didn't work though. See my updated post.

Comment: I've attached a picture, kindly check it.